# @Version JPA/Hibernate Issue

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am having an issue when I use @Version with JPA(Hibernate), When I merge my entity for an existing record it does not fire update statement instead It always fire insert statement.

If I remove @Version from my entity then It works as expected. Do I need to do any special configuration to use @Version ?

Some dependencies in my POM are as below.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Draft-16</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.15.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: That's probably because you're trying to merge an object with a null/0 version. It must have the version that the corresponding row has. That's the point.

Comment: Can you add your entity and how to merge it?

Answer (score 0):

Problem got solved.
As JB Nizet said , I was inserting zero as initial version value instead 1.